# Trim multiple mp3 files at once

Tags: mp3

So, I have hundreds of .mp3 files in a folder. Almost each of them has a period of silence before you can hear a sound. And the periods are of the different size.

The same is with the end of the files.

Is there any application (free, if possible) by which I could trim all the files at once, so that each of them has equal time of silence ( for example five seconds) before and at the end of song.

Or, maybe a mp3 player which can adjust the silence of each song at the described way.

Also, If I must cut all the files one by one, which application is mostu sutable (i.e. speed enough) for this task)?

Comment: http://www.mptrim.com/ Maybe this is of help to you. I haven't used it though.

Comment: @ap0 - the tool you suggest looks like it may not have the ability to calculate start and end silence of arbitrary length... the OP is after something to process the files where the length of silence at the start or end isn't fixed... The problem here is that without knowing a fixed amount of time to remove the average tool won't be very useful. I believe, in this instance, the ability to process the audio is required... thankfully, FFMPEG (free), may be able to come to the rescue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697596/using-ffmpeg-with-silencedetect-to-remove-audio-silence

Comment: @BigChris, thanks for your explanation, but as I can see, I probably must cut each file one by one. Which application is the most sutable, i.e. speed enough for this task ?

Comment: If you're going to need to analyse the silence in each track then it's going to be a big task... if you are going to automate this then FFMPEG should help... the results may not be guaranteed as I am unsure whether you can target the FFMPEG silenceremove filter to the start or end of a track - what defines the end of a track? Rehtorical question, but it's important if you're trying to find a tool to automate and give you the results you desire. You may need to do this one-by-one... Audacity (free) can be used to visibly analyse an audio track so you can work out where needs trimming

Comment: @BigChris, thanks a lot for your help. I think, you should place your post as answer.

Comment: This has been asked here before but cannot find it, anyone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know four methods: [mp3DirectCut](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/mp3dc.html), [Mp3splt-GTK](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/downloads.php), [Mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/downloads.php) or [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

---

### [mp3DirectCut](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/mp3dc.html) (GUI version, best choice for quick results)

- After starting, go to *File » Batch processing*
- Add your mp3 folder, select **Auto crop** and press Start

  [image]

#### Hints

- Choose a different folder as output to test some result files. After verifying, rerun it and choose *Overwrite originals*. You should be done in a couple of seconds since the program doesn't re-encode your mp3 files
- You probably want to enable *Settings » Keep date on overwriting source files*

---

### [Mp3splt-gtk](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/downloads.php) (GUI version, available for all major OS platforms)

- Download $ start the program, click on *Batch & automatic split*
- Select **Trim using silence detection** and press *Batch split*

  [image]

---

### [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/downloads.php) (Command Line version, available for all major OS platforms)

Download [mp3splt](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mp3splt/mp3splt_2.6.2_i386.zip), open your [PowerShell ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx), change both paths and run the following code:

```cs
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\my\musicfolder" -Recurse -Include *.mp3,*.ogg,*.flac
$exe = "C:\path\to\mp3splt.exe"

ForEach ($file in $files) {    
    If ($file.BaseName -notmatch "_trimmed$" ) {        

        $newFile = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.BaseName + "_trimmed" + $file.Extension
        If (Test-Path $newFile) {Remove-Item $newFile }

        & $exe -r -p "th=-48,min=2" `"$file`" | Out-Null

        Remove $file.Fullname
        Rename $($file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.BaseName + "_trimmed" + $file.Extension) $file.Fullname
    }
}
```

[image]

#### Hints

- `-r -p th=-48, min=2` is the option to remove silence at the start/end of your file. `th` defines the threshold level in dB. Everything below is considered as silence. `min=2` sets the minimum silence in seconds. Only silence longer then 2 seconds will be truncated
- You could pretend a test run by adding an uppercase `-P` at the end of mp3splt command. It outputs errors or says everything went well. If used, comment out `Remove` and `Rename` since no new files are created to process them
- For testing, you could also use `-d FOLDERPATH` to choose a single output folder and `-o@f` to use the original filename as output (otherwise `_trimmed` will be appended)

  [Documentation explaining all available options](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/documentation/man.html)

---

### [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (Command Line version, available for all major OS platforms)

FFmpeg's audio filter [`-af silenceremove`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove) should not be used since it always re-encodes your files  and you cannot for gods sake [keep the same audio quality as your input file](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2284211). `-acodec copy` can not be used here. You can only choose one fixed bit rate even if you process multiple files with different qualities.

However, there is another ffmpeg option: [`-af silencedetect`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect). The theory [is already explained at StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25698675/935614) I adopted it to Windows and PowerShell.

Download [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), open your [PowerShell ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx), change both paths and run the following code:

```cs
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\musicfolder" -Recurse -Include *.mp3,*.ogg,*.flac
$ffmpeg = "C:\path\to\ffmpeg.exe"

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    If ($file.BaseName -notmatch "_trimmed$" ) {

        # Detect silence with ffmpeg and "silencedetect". Save the complete output to variable $log
        $log = & $ffmpeg -hide_banner -i `"$file`" -af "silencedetect=duration=1:noise=-50dB" -f null - 2>&1

        $totalLength = [string]$log | where {$_ -match '(?<= Duration:.*)[\d:\.]+' } | % {$matches[0]}        
        $totalLength = ([TimeSpan]::Parse($totalLength)).TotalSeconds

        # Use regex to search all numbers after string "silence_end". Save them as string array in the format XXX.XXX
        # Check if any 'silence_end' was found. If yes, save the first silence ending time as mp3 start time        
        [string[]]$silenceEnd = $log | where {$_ -match '(?<=silence_end: )[-\d\.]+' } | % {$matches[0]}            
        If ($silenceEnd.count -gt 0 -And [double]$silenceEnd[0] -lt $totalLength/2) {
            [double]$trackStart = $silenceEnd[0]
        } else {
            [double]$trackStart = 0
        }

        # Do the same again but for silence starting times. Save the last one as mp3 end time
        [string[]]$silenceStart = $log | where {$_ -match '(?<=silence_start: )[-\d\.]+' } | % {$matches[0]}                
        If ($silenceStart.count -gt 0 -And $silenceStart[$silenceStart.count-1] -gt $totalLength/2) {
            [double]$trackEnd = $silenceStart[$silenceStart.count-1]
        } else {        
            [double]$trackEnd = $totalLength
        } 

        # calculate duration since ffmpeg's -t option wants a duration and not a timestamp
        $duration = $trackEnd - $trackStart

        # Put together the new file name. If file already exists from  previous run, delete it
        $newFile = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.BaseName + "_trimmed" + $file.Extension
        If (Test-Path $newFile) {Remove-Item $newFile }                        

        # Run ffmpeg with our calculated start and duration times to remove silence at start and end
        write-host "$ffmpeg -i `"$file`" -ss $trackStart -t $duration -acodec copy `"$newFile`"  2>&1"
        & $ffmpeg -i `"$file`" -ss $trackStart -t $duration -acodec copy `"$newFile`"  2>&1

        # Delete the original mp3 file and rename the new mp3 file to the original name
        Remove-Item $file.Fullname   
        Rename-Item $newFile $file.Fullname
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a super amazing answer and deserves Community Credit where credit can be found.

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to need to analyse the silence in each track then it's going to be a big task.

If you are going to automate this then FFMPEG should be able to help... the results may not be guaranteed as I am unsure whether you can target the FFMPEG `silenceremove` filter to the start or end of a track - what defines the end of a track? Rhetorical question, but it's important if you're trying to find a tool to automate and give you the results you desire. You may need to do this one-by-one... Audacity (free) can be used to visibly analyse an audio track so you can work out where needs trimming